# How do I get Org mode to recognise the \LaTeX{} macro?

Tags: org-mode

I know you can use inline LaTeX in Org, and that works fine for the most part when exporting to HTML. However, I've not managed to get Org to recognise the `\LaTeX{}` macro properly, unless I enclose it in `$\LaTeX{}$`—but that exports it in italics, which I don't want.

Comment: You can [embed LaTeX code](http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html#Quoting-LaTeX-code) inline. Does that help?

Comment: @Juancho: not for HTML export - latex things are just omitted. It works with $...$ because MathJax takes care of latex things in math mode (including non-math things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$\rm\LaTeX$
```

You might also be able to redefine the \LaTeX macro in MathJax so that it uses an upright font.

EDIT: here's a reference for defining macros for MathJax use: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros